# Extracting part of a URL

Tags: regex, perl, uri

I have used a regex to extract a URI into a Perl variable. I now need to extract a part of this.

For example, say `$2` contains the URI part and the URI may or may not have query parameters i.e it may be in the format `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee` or `/aaa/bbb/ccc?eee=true&fff=false`

I want to extract the first N slashes depending on an argument received by the Perl program. For instance up to `/aaa/bbb` or `/aaa/bbb/ccc`.

The problem I am facing is that the part after third slash may or may not have query parameters.

How do I ignore the query parameters, if they exist?

Comment: Can you please explain your `/aaa/bbb` part. looks like some problem is there in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you ask. It uses the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module, and builds an object from each URL string so that the convenient methods can be used to manipulate the contents

First the query is removed with `$url->query(undef)`. Then the path is split into a list of segments in `@path`, and that list is truncated to the length required

The result is turned back into a string and returned

The program extracts one, two, and three-segment paths from each of the URLs that you gave as an example

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use URI;

my $url1 = '/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee';
my $url2 = '/aaa/bbb/ccc?eee=true&fff=false';

for my $url ( $url1, $url2 ) {
    print trim_path($url, $_), "\n" for 1 .. 5;
    print "\n";
}

sub trim_path {
    my ($url, $n) = @_;
    $url = URI->new($url);

    $url->query(undef);

    my @path = $url->path_segments;
    $url->path_segments( @path[0..$n] ) if $n < $#path;

    return "$url";
}
```

#### output

```
/aaa
/aaa/bbb
/aaa/bbb/ccc
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee

/aaa
/aaa/bbb
/aaa/bbb/ccc
/aaa/bbb/ccc
/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) to handle URIs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use URI;

for my $string (qw( /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee
                    /aaa/bbb/ccc?eee=true&fff=false
)) {
    my $uri = 'URI'->new($string);
    my @path = $uri->path_segments;
    for my $length (1 .. @path - 1) {
        say join "\t", $uri, $length, join '/', @path[ 0 .. $length ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that quoting the class in `'URI'->new($string)` is defensive in some way? What is its purpose?

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, it protects you from Perl parser interpreting `URI->new` as `URI()->new` when such a subroutine exists. It still doesn't protect you from a bareword filehandle `URI` (as in `open URI, '<', $file`), for which you'd need to use `URI::->new`, but I find it too ugly to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function to extract your required information

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $name = '/aaa/bbb/ccc?eee=true&fff=false';
my @val = split(/\?/,$name);
my @parts =split(/\//,$val[0]);
print "@parts\n";
```

Now you can fetch data from `@parts` array depending on your requirement.

output :

```
aaa bbb ccc
```